# override metadata of audio file in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, metadata, id3v2

I would love to have a fix metadata function for my music player, but as I know there is no library that could do such. However I found that some C# application could accomplish this.

[Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Do_Anything_With_ID3.aspx)

I need some advice and probably a good sources to get start this projects. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: I also found this, this is very similar to what I want to do, but there is so few sources.
http://wmpoweruser.com/finally-mp3-tag-editor-for-windows-mobile-available/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the Windows Phone Platform doesn't provide a way to modify song data for songs on the device. There's no way to access the file system from a restricted Silverlight application, and the current [XNA Media classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.aspx) only provide read-only access to song data.

Answer (score 2):

You need direct access to the file via an IsolatedStorage because there is no built-in support to change id3v2 tags.

Then you can use these libraries:

> 1. http://sourceforge.net/projects/audiogenie/
> 2. http://github.com/mono/taglib-sharp

Comment: yes, there are a lot library to work in windows form platform. But the problem is I can't get direct access to a song like a file in my PC. Except that Song's in IsoloateStorage or such.